# Session Timeout not working on classic ASP

Tags: session, timeout

I am working on classic Asp application. I am trying to set the session timeout as 5 minutes. But it's not working. I tried with following solutions but no luck.

1. Tried by setting the `session.timeout = 5`in web.config.
2. Tried by setting the `session.timeout = 5` in global.asa file in both Application and Session event.
3. Set the `session.timeout` property of ASP in IIS.
4. Set the idle timeout of application pool of the web page.

I am using IIS8.5 and server 2012 OS.
Anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to put session.timeout in very top of your pages, before all script tag? Can you show your web.config and global.asa? If success you need to put session.timeout in all pages